# PDF article region identification

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

Which PdfBox APIs can I use for identification of regions where a region is a rectangle encapsulating one article so that I can then extract the text of the article.

I am thinking of parsing the PDF content where large white space areas encapsulating text would be identified as regions.

Here is a code which extracts one region where the size and placement of the region is hard coded:

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File("SevenPropertiesofHighlySecureDevices.pdf"));

PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

// 1 pt is equal to 1/72 inch
Rectangle2D rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,200,200);
String regionName = "First Article Region";
stripper.addRegion(regionName, rectangle);
stripper.extractRegions(pdf.getPage(0));

LOGGER.info("getTextForRegion: \n{}", stripper.getTextForRegion(regionName));
```

If anyone is tempted to "scan" a PDF to find out where the white space areas are so that this information would be used to determine rectangular regions for the purpose of extraction of articles then I would like to let you know that it is very slow and unlikely usable:

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider");
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File("4.pdf"));
PDPage page = pdf.getPage(1);

PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
float docWidth = cropBox.getUpperRightX();
float docHeight = cropBox.getUpperRightY();  
float recWidth = 10;
float rectHeight = 10;
float xStep = recWidth / 2;
float yStep = rectHeight / 2;

String regionName = "docScannerRegion";
String docLeftMarginIndicator = "|";
String docRightMarginIndicator = "|";
String nonTextArea = " ";
String textArea = "-";

PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();

for (float y = 0; y < docHeight; y = y + yStep) {

    System.out.print(docLeftMarginIndicator);

    for(float x = 0; x < docWidth; x = x + xStep) {

        stripper.addRegion(regionName, new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, recWidth, rectHeight));
        stripper.extractRegions(page);
        String txt = stripper.getTextForRegion(regionName).trim();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(txt)) {
            System.out.print(nonTextArea);
        } else {
            System.out.print(textArea);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(docRightMarginIndicator);
}
```

Comment: So you are searching for *large white space areas encapsulating text*. Well, either you render the PDF as bitmap and apply bitmap image analysis, or you extend `PDFGraphicsStreamEngine`, store the location of every object drawn, and look for such encapsulated text.

Comment: @mkl The other idea would be to detect size of the white space between lines and characters. Large spaces would indicate borders of articles, text regions. However I am not sure if this is possible other than using your bitmap and `PDFGraphicsStreamEngine` approach.

Comment: Is it possible to detect line and character white spaces by parsing text information from the PDF as oppose to parse them as an bitmap image?

Comment: Yes, that would be the `PDFGraphicsStreamEngine` solution.  It may not be trivial, though.